# What makes my dog itch all the time?

Tags: dogs, skin-condition, allergies

We have an Indian Spitz who is just 1.5 years old. She is mostly fed indian bread and part of what we have. We have also tried to feed her pet foods like [drools](https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwiljfiGxpLrAhVXDisKHTTHDREYABADGgJzZg&ohost=www.google.com&cid=CAESQOD2eodpc-CBzOcZ12Hv9UhbNG6L9zFm9hBEL5CY3I05ctkXvCR7djnPJd0OsVwU-PjNhMhjdu_YZaoe_ZaCgH8&sig=AOD64_0e2-DSVjosg2N_YCpMfNmchhzZyg&ctype=5&q=&ved=2ahUKEwjF5uyGxpLrAhULILcAHby9BTEQ9aACegQIExBf&adurl=) but she doesn't prefer it and mostly prefers milk.

We noticed that she has been continuously itching for some weeks now, which doesn't stop even after a wash. Also, there is this peculiar rash under her neck that seems to have removed her hair from the region. I have attached the pics below.

**What could be the reason for this and how should I remedy it ?**

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: We can only guess over the internet. You should take your dog to a vet to test for allergies or other skin conditions or bugs.

Comment: it is a lot better to give your dog clean water and regular dog food and no milk at all,adult animals and people do not need any milk at all in their diet,giving milk can cause dehydration and malnutrition in mamals.to diagnose skin problems you need to ask your vet for help,diagnosing skin problems is not something you want random people on the net to do.

Comment: Looks like a rash but who knows for sure, the cause like previous comment mentions, could be the diet. Better to feed the dog, dog food